# glDrawArrays crashing in iOS - multiple Line Strip

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es

I'm getting a crash in the following code:

```
-(void)EAGLViewNeedsRedraw:(EAGLView *)EAGLView {
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glLoadIdentity();

   glTranslatef(-100.0f, -60.0f, -180.0f);
   glMultMatrixf(transform);

   glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &fiber_model_vertices[0]);
   glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

   // Do the drawing
   for (int i=0; i<[tracF num_fibers];i++) {
           glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 
                 [tracF array_offset:i], 
                 [tracF num_vertices_for_fiber:i]);
    }
}
```

It crashes after 276 calls to `glDrawArrays`. Is there any limit on the number of `glDrawArrays` calls?

Comment: What values do `-array_offset:` and `-num_vertices_for_fiber:` return? Is your array big enough for those values to be meaningful?

Comment: yes they are big enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem.

It seems a limitation in the Vertex Buffer Objects. When I disable the VBO the program don't crash anymore.

Comment: how do you disable the VBO?